# Disable Copy constructor of template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

How can I disable the copy constructor of a template class.

E.g.:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
    T property;
    constexpr X(const T property): property(property) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const X& x) {
        return out << "{ " << x.property << " }";
    }
};
```

The Problem:

If I let the class contain itself

```
constexpr X x1 { 1 };
std::cout << x1 << "\n"; // prints "{ 1 }"
constexpr X x2 { x1 };
std::cout << x2 << "\n"; // prints "{ 1 }", expected "{ { 1 } }"
```

My Hypothesis is that the copy constructor is called.
Deleting the copy constructor does not help. Then I get a compile time error.

Comment: `Deleting the copy constructor does not help.` How did you it?

Comment: Something something template parameter inference.  Fix that, and the copy constructor won't even be a candidate for construction of `x2`.

Comment: I deleted the copy constructor by `constexpr X(const X&) = delete;`.

Comment: Note that you *don't* want to delete or disable the copy constructor, because your ctor-initializer list in the instantiation of `X<X<int>>` is going to need it.

Comment: Your example does not compile. It works after fixes
https://ideone.com/sLdeKH

Comment: Yes, I updated it.

Comment: Proof that the parameter inference is the problem: https://rextester.com/NGW62945

Comment: @BenVoigt I do not understand your comments. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You want `x1` to be `struct X<int> { int property; X(const int arg) : property(arg) {} };` and `x2` to be `struct X<X<int>> { X<int> property; X(const X<int> arg2) : property(arg2) {} };`   That `property(arg2)` copies the constructor argument into the member data, hence you need the copy-constructor enabled.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah ok, I knew that this works, but I want to infer the types. Is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible if you provide the correct inference helper function.  Work on that, the copy constructor is a total red herring.

Comment: Ok, that was just a hypothesis :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of a helper function?

Comment: You will need what's called a [User-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)   Sorry I don't have enough experience with this yet to provide a better explanation than what you can read there.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, but thats a point from where I can start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template helper function

```
template<typename T>
X<T> helper(const T& x) {
    return x;  // This will invoke the construtor
}
```

then when using

```
helper(x1);
```

the type `T` will be correctly found to be `X<int>`.

Comment: I think it is kind of ugly to do it this way, but it works! Thanks.
I guess that is also the reason for make_unique etc.?

Comment: @ArwedMett: Well `make_unique` and similar functions were made in versions of C++ that didn't have Class Template Argument Deduction in variable declarations at all.  For C++17 and later, you want a deduction guide instead of a factory function.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found a nicer solution for C++17 thanks to Ben Voigt.

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
    T property;
    constexpr X(const T property): property(property) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const X& x) {
        return out << "{ " << x.property << " }";
    }
};
```

You need to add a deduction guide:

```
template<typename T>
X(X<T>) -> X<X<T>>;
```